# Is there a way to add a quote inside smart quotes?

Tags: punctuation

Is there a way to add a quote within smart quotes?

Let's say I need to render something like "volonta'" (notice how there's a ' + " symbol at the end of the word), how would I do that?

So far I've tried ``` ``volonta''' ``` and ``` ``volonta\rq'' ``` but none of these seems to yield the proper result.

Any hints?

Comment: To begin with, you should not write “volonta'” with an apostrophe, but with an accent: ``volont\`a`` (or `volontà` if you use `inputenc` with the proper option). Using an apostrophe in place of the accent is a bad grammatical error in Italian.

Comment: @egreg I see, thanks. I wonder if there's any instrument for converting aeiou + accent into their equivalent form (e.g. à) since I don't have an Italian keyboard.

Comment: You can input it as ``volont\`a``. However, every modern keyboard allows to input accented letters with some dead key system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you separate the single quote, `'`, from the double-quote, `''`, with a thinspace, `\,`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
``volonta'\,''
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `'{}''`?

Comment: @egreg - That would leave only a barely perceptible space between the single smart quote and the double smart quote. I assumed that a bit more space is called for. However, I may be mistaken. Let's see if the OP weighs in and clarifies what he/she is looking to get.

Comment: Well, the example doesn't really make sense, actually.

Comment: @Mico's solution looks better IMHO, since it leaves a little bit more space between the single quote and the closing double quote. Thank you both.